# Why is react-native-svg-icons giving me the error that there are some duplicates for ttf files?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, font-awesome, react-native-elements

**Long story short**

I have sunk about 12 hours in my iPhone `react-native` app. Since yesterday it's not building anymore (out of nowhere). After 5 hours! of debugging I found what may caused the issue but not how to solve it.

I use these packages containing .ttf files / for icons and stuff:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core"
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
"@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome"
"@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios"
"react-native-vector-icons"
```

And I think there is the problem. Since react-native-vector-icons seems to use also the same .ttf file that one of these packages bring in I get the error:

> Multiple Commands produce...

So when I uninstall `react-native-vector-icons` it works again. But then when I get to the screen where i use this package:

`"react-native-elements"` (which in the docs it says it needs `react-native-vector-icons`)

It's complaining that it can't find Fontawesome Icons (the Checkbox Component from elements)

So how can I fix this? I need the app to build obviously and also need the Checkbox Component from `react-native-elements`. But `react-native-elements` requires `react-native-svg-icons`. But when I install it it doesn't even build with the above error that there are multiple .ttf files of the same icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure it out but it has something to do with `react-native-elements` since they also link the icons that also come with `react-native-vector-icons`

I solved it by getting rid of `react-native-elements` and created my own custom Checkbox component.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue associated with the fonts included in the react-native-vector-icons library. I solved it with the following.

1. I created `assets/fonts` dir in my project. I added another some fonts that iOS didn't have linked ("Nunito" font in my case), but I didn't include fonts of react-native-vector-icons
2. I created a new file named `react-native.config.js` in the root of my project with the following:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

3. Then I ran `react-native link`
4. Then I went to `ios` dir (`cd ios`) and ran `pod update`
5. Finally, I ran `react-native run-ios` and the magic happened

I bassed it on Alex Biddle's post: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-your-react-native-project-c64305281b9

Comment: As links can become invalid every relevant information should be in the answer! Did you add everything that's relevant from your link?

Comment: I didn't write some about my issue... Let me edit my answer. Thanks